# Wording date format to number date format

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, datetime-format

I am creating a query in MS Access 2010.
There are two strings that I have to compare and find the cycle time.

**1:**  Wednesday, February 12, 2013 12:47 AM
**2:**  11/15/2012 4:03:32 PM

I was trying to convert one into other format but I don't have sufficient knowledge.
Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Where is Wednesday, February 12, 2013 12:47 AM coming from? Are you sure that the field is a text field? If it is a date field, the format does not matter, just compare the dates.

Comment: I extracted this from outlook. It's the part of the e-mail body content, so it's definitely a string.

Comment: You just need to lose Wednesday : cdate("February 12, 2013 12:47 AM")

Comment: In full, `cdate(Mid("Wednesday, February 12, 2013 12:47 AM",Instr("Wednesday, February 12, 2013 12:47 AM",",")+1))`, but I am sure you have field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you discard the weekday name from your first string, you can use `CDate` to convert it to a Date/Time value.  Here is an Immediate window session ...

```vb
DateString1 = "Wednesday, February 12, 2013 12:47 AM"
? Mid(DateString1, InStr(DateString1, " "))
 February 12, 2013 12:47 AM
Date1 = CDate(Mid(DateString1, InStr(DateString1, " ")))
? Date1
2/12/2013 12:47:00 AM
```

Although the substring I gave `CDate` started with a space, `CDate` doesn't care.

Your second string appears suitable for `CDate` as is.

```vb
DateString2 = "11/15/2012 4:03:32 PM"
Date2 = CDate(DateString2)
? Date2
11/15/2012 4:03:32 PM
```

Once you have the two Date/Time values, you can compute your cycle time.  I'm not sure what you have in mind there, but here are some alternatives for you to consider.

```vb
? Date1 - Date2
 88.3635185185121 
? DateDiff("d", Date2, Date1)
 89 
? DateDiff("h", Date2, Date1)
 2120
```